# In Beamer, is it possibly to change itemize margins in the middle of an itemize environment

Tags: beamer, itemize

In LaTeX/Beamer, is it possible to change the margins of an itemize environment halfway through the environment itself? Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1]
    \item \lipsum[1][2]
    \item[] \lipsum[1][4]
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image]

What I want is for the third item to line up to the start of the bullets, rather than the start of the text of the previous two items. (I'm aware that I could just end the itemize environment and write the last item as its own paragraph, but there are other reasons why I want to do everything as part of an itemized list.)

Answer (score 1):

Dirty hack:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1][1]
    \item \lipsum[1][2]
    \item[] \hspace{-0.6cm}\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1][4]}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa appromimatly yes (labelsep), but I think in this case a numeric value is easier to finetune

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it now. Most of my ingenious ideas don't work `:-)`

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I assume there's no way to precisely calculate what the numeric value should be?